# Display simple calendar on screen in python S60 (pyS60)

Tags: python, calendar, s60, pys60

I am trying to develop a simple calendar based application using pyS60. I need to display a calendar as part of the form. I have searched but I couldn't find anything useful in the e32calendar documentation. I can get a calendar on the canvas but its not interactive. But i want one which is interactive ( just like inbuilt calendar in Nokia Mobiles). I don`t need the event classes though.

Am I missing something?

TIA
Chirag Narula

Answer (score 0):

Python module for py60 has a calendar module, which provides calendar services like reading, creating entries, setting alarms.
Please look into the documentation at http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/PyS60

In Doc, Section 7.2.2 provides a way to do that :

CalendarDb objects represent a live view into the database. If an entry is changed outside your Python application, the changes are visible immediately, and conversely any changes you commit into the database are visible immediately to other applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All this is getting really confusing to me. I think I am just not getting it. Actually what I want is the main display with the calendar. And if I press key on a particular date, it stores that date and also highlights that date. 
What am I not getting here? Where am I going here? What do I need to learn or understand?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at 

http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/PyS60_applications

It has lot of calendar applications.